# Attach an image to an email

Tags: ios, ipad

I was wondering if there is a way to allow the user to select an image from the camera roll, and then attach it to an email?

Here is the code I have now:

```
-(IBAction) openEmail {

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TPsecondary_Example@email.com", nil]];
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Learning Trail Submission"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:emailbody isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Answer" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/xml" fileName:@"Answer.plist"];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, In order to continue to receive answers to your questions, you'll want to start marking correct answers as correct.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is!

In your .h file add these delegates and declare a `UIImage` named selectedImage.

```
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Then in your .m you can add the following.

Link `-(IBAction)openImagePicker:(id)sender` to the button that you want to start the process.

```
- (IBAction)openImagePicker:(id)sender
{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self openEmail];
    }];

}

-(IBAction) openEmail {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TPsecondary_Example@email.com", nil]];
        [mailComposer setSubject:@"Learning Trail Submission"];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:emailbody isHTML:NO];
        [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Answer" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/xml" fileName:@"Answer.plist"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 1.0);
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData  mimeType:@"image/jpg"   fileName:@"imageTitle"];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Mind you this is a very basic example that doesn't handle events such as the user selecting a video instead of an image...

Comment: @Freedom4ever Keep me posted, and let me know if it works out. If it doesn't, I should be able to make a couple of tweaks.

Comment: @Freedom4ever `UIImagePickerController~ doesn't support multiple selection, and what doesn't work?

Comment: it crashes when i press the button linked

Comment: is there any way to attach multiple images?

Comment: Not with anything that Apple provides, you'd have to create your own image picker from scratch using queries for AVAssets

Comment: @Freedom4ever check out this link, it's a project designed to allow multiple selection of images https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController